# How to call a function inside CodeIgniter's controller using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I've been trying to figure out how to call a function in a controller from within a javascript/jquery script. The function is called **do_search** and I need to call it from the script in the view. It needs to be called inside the else condition. All I've found on the internet is using AJAX, but I will forward the user to a new page anyway so I just need to call the function.

I'd like to thank you in advance for reading this and most importantly for your replies.

**controller**

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();


    }

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('test_view');

    }

    public function do_search() {
        <!-- Implementation of search query to the DB -->
        $this->load->view('search_results_view');
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="navigation_bar">
            <div id="search">
                <form>

                    <div id="do_search_btn" class="menu" style="display: none;">
                        <p id="center">Do Search</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="search_field" class="menu" style="display: none;">
                        <input type="text" name="search_field_input" id="search_input" value="Type in here">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                $( "#do_search_btn" ).click(function() {

                    var input = $("[name='search_field_input']").val();

                    if(input ==""){
                    $("[name='search_field_input']").val("Enter search 1st");

                    }
                    else if(input=="Type in here")
                    {
                        $("[name='search_field_input']").val("Enter search 1st");
                    }
                    else if(input=="Enter search 1st")
                    {
                        $("[name='search_field_input']").val("Enter search 1st");
                    }
                    else {
                    <!-- CALL THE FUNCTION FROM THE CONTROLLER HERE PLEASE -->
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: use `$.ajax`, `$.get` or `$.post`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, then it's simple to use ajax to call a function in a controller. An example:

```
if(input ==""){
   $("[name='search_field_input']").val("Enter search 1st");
}
else if(input=="Type in here")
{
   $("[name='search_field_input']").val("Enter search 1st");
}
else if(input=="Enter search 1st")
{
   $("[name='search_field_input']").val("Enter search 1st");
}
else {

   $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test/do_search',
            data:{'search':input},
            success:function(data){
                $('#resultdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
}
```

In the controller you can access the posted data like so:

```
public function do_search() {
$search = $this->input->post('search');
<!-- Implementation of search query to the DB -->
$this->load->view('search_results_view');
}
```

`#resultdiv` is just a `<div>` that you could place the result of the search in, if you wanted.

Comment: Alright, and could you please tell me how can I then work with the processed value? In which variable is it stored in? And also what does the #resultdiv refer to?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one additional question. If I would have two or more input fields how would I process those? Let's say apart from <input type="text" name="search_field_input" I would also have one with name "another field". Is that going to turn the $search into array or how does that work? I really appreciate the help, this should be the last thing I'd like to know.

Comment: In that case, in the `data` part of the `ajax` call, use comma-separated values, e.g.: `data:{'search':input, 'blah':blah}`. Then in the controller you could access it with `$blah = $this->input->post('blah')`.

Comment: IF there is any chance you will read this, could you possibly contact me at `james.belik@gmail.com` ? I have just implemented all the above, but am getting server error 500. I'd really appreciate it man.